# jQuery to trigger a click on an iFrame?

Tags: jquery

If a user clicks on an image I want that to simultaneously trigger a click on a specified iFrame as well. Is that possible? The image and iFrame are located on the same page. If so, can you please show me the code that would work?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="image" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png">

<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.test.com" height= "100" width="160"></iframe>

<script>
jQuery("input.image").click(function(){
   $("#iframe").click()
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's better that you try to do it, then if you find a problem post the code for resolving it together :)

Comment: OK I just updated my original question with the code for what I got so far.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your jquery image selector is wrong.

change

```
jQuery("input.image")
```

to

```
$("#image")
```

Then everything will work. You can see it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6WUn/)

**Post Edit**

If the question is to trigger a click on one of the elements contained in the iFrame, then replace the

```
$("#iframe").click()
```

with something like:

```
$("#iframe").contents().find("a:first").click();
```

This will only work if the contents of the main page and the iFrame's page are on the same domain. Otherwise browsers will prevent the action as it is cross site scripting. You can see in your example, XSS prevention will occur as demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3Srw/1/)

Comment: This is working, sort of. Even though I get the alert that says "iframe clicked" it doesn't appear to actually be clicking the iFrame because the content inside the actual iFrame, if it was truly being clicked, would open up another window and that's not happening.

Comment: Your question asked to trigger a click on the iFrame. Thats what is happening in my example. I take it that you are interested in triggering a click on an element that resides as content inside the iFrame?

Comment: @ dcarson - Yes, that is correct; sorry I wasn't clear. I need it to click on the content inside the iFrame. Specifically, there is a link within the iFrame content that I need it to click on. Here is a copy of the actual iFrame content. You can see the link I need it to click, it is the only link within the iFrame content. http://pastebin.com/cXsuq71P

Comment: @ dcarson - I'm looking at your most recent post edit above where you mention the content being on another domain. The link within the iFrame content that I am trying to click is a different domain.

Comment: If that is the case, then all modern browsers will disallow the action. There is not much you can do about this. If you open up the javascript console for the browser that you are using, you'll see something like: "Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.test.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match." Also, If I have helped you, please mark my question as answered and upvote it. Thanks :)

Comment: That's too bad. Let me know if you think of any other way I can accomplish that, and thanks for your help.

Comment: This is 7 years late, but, maybe it will help someone else. If you have control over the content in the iframe, you can simply reload the iframe with a query string, then look for that query string using PHP, ASP.net or JavaScript and trigger some action based on the supplied query string.

If you don't have control over the content of the iframe, you're out of luck. There's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 3):

I think you needed something like this:-

```
$("#image").click(function(){
     var $iframe = $("#iframe").contents();
     $("body", $iframe).trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: I tried this and when I click the image, nothing happens to the iFrame. The content of the iFrame is also an image, but the image in the iFrame is a hyperlink. So when I click on the image, it should also trigger a click on the iFrame which should open up a new page because the image in the iFrame is a link.

Comment: Please check. I added the new answer.