# node-phantom handle hyperlink of iframe fail

Tags: node.js, iframe, phantomjs

Recently, i integrate node and phantomjs by [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node). I opened page that has iframe element, i can get the hyperlink element of iframe, but failed when i execute click on it.
Do you have a way? Anyone can help me?

example:

```
page.open(url);
...
page.evaluate(function(res){
              var childDoc = $(window.frames["iframe"].document),
              submit = childDoc.find("[id='btnSave']"),
              cf = submit.text();//succeed return text  
              submit.click()//failed   
          return cf;
      },function(res){
              console.log("result="+res);//result=submit
              spage.render("test.png");//no submit the form
              ph.exit();

      });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute stuff in an iframe. You can only read from it. You even created a new document from the iframe, which will only contain the textual representation of the iframe, but it is in no way linked to the original iframe.

You would need to use [`page.switchToFrame`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/switch-to-frame.html) to switch to the frame to execute stuff **on** the frame without copying it first.

It looks like `switchToFrame` is not implemented in phantomjs-node. You could try [node-phantom](https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom).

If the iframe is on the same domain you can try the following from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16929176/1816580):

```
submit = $("iframe").contents().find("[id='btnSave']")
cf = submit.text();
submit.click()
```

If the iframe is not from the same domain, you will need to create the page with web security turned off:

```
phantom.create('--web-security=false', function(page){...});
```