# clicking an element ID inside iframe.document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var iframe = $('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('idclick');
iframe.click()
```

this clicks an element id but throws undefined so I cannot process anything after iframe.click()

Why does it show undefined but yet clicks? Is it because I'm mixing jquery with javascript? If so, how would I write this either fully on jquery or js.

A solution with both jquery and js is + point, I'd like to see the difference.

ISSUE:

```
var iframe is undefined.
```

Comment: Does it say what is undefined?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Huangism I'm assuming var iframe is undefined? As it says undefined, right after the .click() statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the content of an iframe with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796619/how-to-access-the-content-of-an-iframe-with-jquery)

Comment: Check the dupe question, your problem is getting content in the iframe. Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928860/jquery-to-trigger-a-click-on-an-iframe is actually a more precise dupe

Comment: That doesn't help me with the syntax.